# How to write wiremock stub definition for Request Body having JSON as a payload

Tags: java, wiremock

Can any one help me in writting stub definition for Request Body with regex as value can be any thing for the attributes

```
  {
    "Parent": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "price": "$67.00",
       "value": 67

    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "price": "$67.00",
       "value": 67,
    }
 ]
}
```

I am able to write the stub if i have to check with static values , but i need to match it with regex, any help is appreciated

Comment: use json2POJO generator for generating POJO(Stub) classes.

Comment: it is wiremock stub i need to create

Comment: What part of the documentation on [JSON RegEx matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#regex-matching) doesn't work for you and what error is presented?